# Checking whether or not two strings are identical in size and hold identical values

Tags: javascript

```
string1 = prompt("String 1?");
string2 = prompt("String 2?");

if (string1.length == string2.length)
    alert (string1 + " and " + string2 + " : are identical in size.") 
        else
    alert (string1 + " and " + string2 + " : not identical in size.") 

for(i=0; i<string1.length; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<string2.length; j++)
        {
        if (string1.charAt[i] == string2.charAt[i])
            alert (string1.charAt[i] + " and " + string2.charAt[j] + " : are identical values.")
                else
            alert (string1.charAt[i] + " and " + string2.charAt[j] + " : are non-identical values.")
        }
    };
```

The second part of the code keeps returning "undefined" and "undefined". I'm trying to compare both strings to see if they hold identical values. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is your intention to "compare both strings to see if they hold identical values" as in your problem description, in which case why not just say `if (string1 === string2`) like in InviS's answer, or to actually give lots of alert messages indicating exactly which characters are the same and which are different as in your code?

Comment: P.S. You may want to stop and get your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7942274/615754) working before moving on...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me - I tend to jump ahead of myself sometimes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong index when you compare the characters. This:

```
if (string1.charAt[i] == string2.charAt[i])
```

should be:

```
if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j))
```

Besides using parantheses, as Rob W pointed out, you should use the variable `j` to access the character in `string2`.

I'm not sure why you are comparing each character in one string with every character in the other string, though... If you actually want to compare each character to the corresponding character in the other string, then you should not have nested loops but a single loop.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that nested loops don't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use `charAt(i)` instead of `charAt[i]` (parentheses instead of square braces).
**[`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)** is a String method, not a string's property.

Equivalent methods:

```
string1[i]
string1.charAt(i)
string1.substr(i, 1)
string.substring(i, i+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wtf?

```
string1 === string2
```

Why not?

Comment: @jeansymolanza: That's not how you compare strings in JavaScript. It's not C. Even if it was, `strcmp` would work.

Comment: why your way to compare strings is so difficult?! If you need compare arrays use underscore.js :) Useful library!

Comment: Its for optional lab practicals I'm doing at uni - have to use what we've learnt so far!

Comment: ))) We have something like that. Labs that have no sence :) Good luck!