# Comparing two strings for identical values

Tags: javascript

```
// Write a program to check whether or not two arrays are identical in size, and hold identical values

string1 = prompt("String 1?");
string2 = prompt("String 2?");

compareNum = 0;

for(i=0; i<string1.length; i++)
{
    for(j=i; j<string2.length; j++)
    {
    if (string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(j))
{
        compareNum++;
        break;
}
    }
};

alert("We found " + compareNum + " identical value(s).");
```

I've managed to build a relatively simple string comparison program but now the problem I have is the result it outputs.

For example if I type in "Jeansy" and "Jeansy" - I get the response of "We found 6 identical values."

Whereas if I type in "Molanza" and "Molanza" - I get the reply of "We found 9 identical values."

Surely it should only be 7?

Or does the 'a' get counted twice? Is there anyway I can negate this?

Btw I'm taking into account all strings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you are comparing every letter in string1 with every letter in string2. If there are duplicate letters you'll get duplicate results.

Try this:

```
string1 = prompt("String 1?");
string2 = prompt("String 2?");
compareNum = 0; // why are you using the Number contructor? Unneeded.

l = Math.min(string1.length, string2.length);
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(i)) compareNum++;
}

// do something with compareNum.
```

Comment: Start at the beginning of the strings, compare character 0 with character 0, char1 with char1, and so on, advancing one character at a time through both strings. The `Math.min` makes sure you don't go past the end of either string. Precomputing `l` just makes the `for` statement tidier, I don't know if it has any performance impact.

Comment: Why are we comparing string1 with string1 - and not string2?

Comment: Did I say string1? I said char1. As in "character in position 1".

Comment: Ok but we are comparing two strings that are exactly the same in the for loop. If I type in "Jeansy" and "Molanza" - compareNum is 6.

Comment: +1 for remembering that the strings may have different lengths.

Comment: Now when I type in "Jeansy" and "Molanza" - compareNum is 0

Comment: That is correct. J-M, e-o, a-l, n-a, s-n, y-z = no matches. Or were you looking for "any position, just avoid duplicates"? If that is the case, use your old code but have the second loop as `for(j=i; j<...)` so that you don't compare stuff you've already compared.

Comment: I've taken my old code and used "for(j=i; j<string2.length; j++)" and used the "Molanza"/"Molanza" test but it now returns compareNum as 8!

Comment: Okay, try adding `break` after the `compareNum++` (make sure to add braces around the two so that the loop affects both statements).

Comment: It works perfectly fine now as "Molanza"/"Molanza returns 7. But an example such as "Jeansy"/"Molanza" still returns compareNum as 0!

Comment: You didn't put the `{ ... }` around the contents of the `if`, so it's `break`ing whether or not it finds a match.

Comment: Sorry about that I've made the changes!

Answer (score 2):

You're looping over each character in string 1 and comparing it to each character in string 2--but you're looping over string 2 for *every* character in string 1.

The indices for each string should be the same; you don't need two loops.

How you handle strings whose lengths are different depends on your requirements.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the help - I used two loops hoping to compare all the letters in the strings no matter the length.

Comment: But that's not what you want to do. How to handle strings of different lengths depends on what you want to do, but you should probably just stop comparing once you've exceeded the length of one of them. Or define "compare" more precisely.

Comment: Yes you are right there. By comparison I mean how many occurrences of a single letter occur in both strings. For example: "Jupiter" and "Mars" have a 1 occurrence of the same letter whereas "Dave" and "Saved" have 4 different occurrences of the same letter. In the future once I get good enough I want to expand it to alert the letter and how many occurrences in both strings it has.

Comment: Oh; you might be better off using a map (or array index by character, essentially the same thing) since you'll end up with something like that eventually anyway. This definitely changes the problem statement and the solution; you really need a map of some sort.

Comment: Could you please link me to any websites with examples?

Comment: @jeansymolanza Of what, maps? (Or the JS equivalent, anyway.) You can just say `var m = {};` then as you encounter characters, `m[c] = 1`. Do this for the first string. Then go over the second string, if there's already an entry for the character, increment the counter. If there isn't already an entry, it doesn't matter, because you're just looking for duplicates. In the end, the entries in the map with count > 1 are the chars in both strings. (Maybe, that's kind of off the top of my head :/